# Understading internals of vi editor

Tags: linux, unix, vi

I am currently writing my own shell program. My current shell can just execute commands.
I want to go a step future and execute vi from this new shell. I am trying to understand the internals of how a vi editor works , but no good articles on net.

Any pointers or links would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you fork() -> exec() the vi executable with parameters
then wait() in the parent? (your shell).

You can do this with a system() call as well.  In fact if you want to see how system works, download glibc code.

```
int main()
{
  system("vi t.lis");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the source code:  http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/

I'm not sure what you mean by "execute vi from this new shell".  How is it different from any other command?

Comment: Well, when I type vi on the new shell , the editor is launched but I am unable to type anything .And  also I get back my new shell prompt waiting for the next command to be typed.

I am unable to type anything on the screen and my program just hangs.

any clue?